# PHP-FPM how do I suppress notice log level and still capture warning log /etc/php-fpm.conf

Tags: configuration, php

I'm having trouble figuring out how to suppress notice level log events in php-fpm such as the following:

```
[07-Feb-2015 10:06:48] NOTICE: [pool www] child 19591 exited with code 0 after 52040.698062 seconds from start
[07-Feb-2015 10:06:49] NOTICE: [pool www] child 17234 started
[07-Feb-2015 10:06:50] NOTICE: [pool www] child 19822 exited with code 0 after 52014.845635 seconds from start
[07-Feb-2015 10:06:50] NOTICE: [pool www] child 17261 started
[07-Feb-2015 10:07:33] NOTICE: [pool www] child 17784 exited with code 0 after 52246.014015 seconds from start
```

while still capturing log events of type warning as would be created by error_log() function in php for example.  Log events such as the following:

```
 [07-Feb-2015 11:46:44] WARNING: [pool www] child 32465 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: Array"
 [07-Feb-2015 11:46:44] WARNING: [pool www] child 32465 said into stderr: "("
 [07-Feb-2015 11:46:44] WARNING: [pool www] child 32465 said into stderr: "     [6] => 363"
 [07-Feb-2015 11:46:44] WARNING: [pool www] child 32465 said into stderr: ")"
 [07-Feb-2015 11:46:44] WARNING: [pool www] child 32465 said into stderr: ""
```

from php.net it states the variable log_level accecpts the following string types to adjust the level of logging captured:

Error log level. Possible values: alert, error, warning, notice, debug. Default value: notice.

http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php

So, naturally in my /etc/php-fpm.conf file I set the configuration value to:
log_level: warning and service restart.  I then get NONE of the log events described above.

I cannot find anywhere where the documentation indicates what each log_level option does and further it seems that anything other than notice suppresses everything.

This is using php-fpm 5.4 or 5.5 on a centOS machine.

Comment: My team and I are having the same problem on PHP 7.0, deployed in a Docker image based on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I got rid of notices by changing error_reporting in the corresponding php.ini.

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE
```

This means: report all errors but deprecation, strict and notice types.

The log level seems to be the wrong place to tweak.